# How to find broken links in a website using Cypress?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress, broken-links

How can I find all broken links in a website using Cypress if there are any? Are there any plugins to use?

If not, how should I write my code that I can see whether the link returns a `200` status (or a successful link)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
cy.request('yourlink')
  .should((response) => {
    expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this but it's giving me an error!

Comment: Get or Post and show me your code with cy.request, Which problem do you have, show logs.

Comment: If by link the OP means an `<a>` element, then perhaps you need to get the element, get its `href` attribute, and then call `cy.request` on the `href` element's value?

Comment: This is my code: cy.get("a").each($a => {
            const message = $a.text()
            expect($a, message).to.have.attr("href").not.contain("undefined")
          })
          cy.request("a[href]").should(response => {
            expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
          }).

Comment: It looks like it shows me the undefined links, but we can have broken links for so many reasons so I need to get the links and make sure they each work and return a successful message (200). This test is for all the inks available on the website and not just one and I am just showing the last part of my code. I need the test to crawl on the website and find the broken links. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

for the first a selection `a[href*="yourdomain.com"]` the reason I didn't include "www" is because for my project we link to subdomains as well so I needed to include these.

for the second half, `:not([href=""]`, again for my project we had links like this for some reason so I had to make sure to NOT include it.

`$el.prop("href")` fetches the href value from the DOM element.

I'm using `cy.request()` to send a HTTP request to the URL and make sure that it returns `200` thus proving that the page exists.

Here's the code:

```
cy.get('a[href*="yourdomain.com"]:not([href=""])').each(($el) => {
  cy.request($el.prop("href")).as("link");
});

cy.get("@link").should((response) => {
  expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
});
```

You can use this for any page. You can have your pages listed out in your `cypress.json` file or you can do it programatically as a regression test.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way to do it:

```
 cy.request("yourLink")
```

Yes, no need to add any assertions. because by default there's an assertion that the response is not 404. so this line is more than enough.

---

If you want to go the extra mile and test all the links in the page, here's what to do:

```
 cy.get('a').each(link => {
    cy.request(link.prop('href'))
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

This should make a request to all the available links with a tag in the page.

```
  cy.visit(link)
   cy.get('a').each(page => {
   cy.request(page.prop('href'))
})
```